# SQLMap command SSL error

Tags: ssl, sql-injection, sqlmap

I have an application running on Apache 2.4.33 and we are trying to test the sql injection vulnerability for this application using the SQLMap command as below:

```
sqlmap -u 'http://hostip/appurl?query_type=something&element=*' -D check -T configuration --dump
```

The application is runnig on ssl 443 port and when the above url is hit through browser it gets redirected to https, similar thing happens in the above command and we see the following:

```
[00:02:01] [INFO] testing connection to the target URL
sqlmap got a 302 redirect to 'https://hostip/appurl?query_type=something&element=. Do you want to follow? [Y/n] n
```

and this utility works properly.

```
sqlmap -u 'https://hostip/appurl?query_type=something&element=' -D check -T configuration --dump
```

However when we directly try to do the sqlmap command on the url which it was getting redirected we get 500 internal server error.

The Apache access log show:

10.21.12.170 - - [03/Jul/2018:12:51:12 +0530] "GET https://hostip/appurl?query_type=something&element= HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: Also this should be asked on https://security.stackexchange.com